# Does AdBlock Plus work with Firefox in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox-extensions, adblock

I have AdBlock Plus on my Windows machines running Firefox but I cannot find it in the Firefox add-ons in Ubuntu. Am I missing something or does it not work on Firefox for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use it on Firefox in Ubuntu, and you can install it [here](https://adblockplus.org/) from their official website.

If you, for some reason, need a version of AdBlock Plus that is compatible with older versions of Firefox, look [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/versions/).

Comment: I visited the official site and got an error message that it  is not compatable with Firefox 7.0.1

Comment: @perzaklie Where in the world did you find firefox 7.0.1? I'm running version 26.0 on my Debian.

Comment: @perzaklie Firefox 7.0.1 is amazingly outdated. If you look around on the site, however, I edited my answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Adblock Plus extension for Firefox in Ubuntu
https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lucid/adblock-plus/

Comment: -1 as there is no download link to the extension at that URL.

Comment: Thanks all! I now have Firefox 26.0 and all my add-ons synced from my Windows machine! How I ended up with 7.0, it installed when I re-installed Ubuntu. I never paid attention to the version! My bad!